# Using function both as interactive command and in elisp code

Tags: interactive, completing-read

I am trying to understand the use of the `interactive` and the `intern` commands so I can use a function both within an interactive context and an elisp context.

Require some explanation of how `intern` is setting up the variable `style` for use with the `(setq show-paren-style style)` command.

How would one call the function in elisp code?

```
(defun richerenkov-view-parens (style)
  "Visualise parentheses and expressions using STYLE.
STYLE must be a symbol."
  (interactive
   (list
    (intern (completing-read "Visualise: "
       '("bracemk" "expression" "mixed") nil t "mixed"))))
  (setq show-paren-style style))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(intern "bracemk")` returns the canonical symbol `bracemk` the same as you would get from using `'bracemk`.

Hence: `(richerenkov-view-parens 'bracemk)`

Note also the docstring: "STYLE must be a symbol" -- so you know in advance that you need to pass a symbol as the argument.

Refer to <kbd>M-x</kbd> `elisp-index-search` <kbd>RET</kbd> `intern` <kbd>RET</kbd>

Comment: Right.  In brief, `intern` is only used when using the function interactively, to change the word into a symbol.  When the function in used in elisp code (where the function is not called interactively) one uses the symbol immediately that is passed directly to `show-paren-style`.

Comment: Yes, exactly so.

Comment: Great.  Looks like `completing-read` inside the interactive expression should match the arguments to the function.